How to implement a VPN server deployment without a static IP address?
My ISP (Airtel Fiber India) provided IP is not static and it also does not match with one which I find with Google.
I don't really understand how this works but its something like my ISP has set a virtual network in which I have been provided one of the LAN IPv4 address but it is acting as my WAN IP so how do I deploy a website?
I was trying to deploy a VPN server to access my work data on the go.


its something like my ISP has set a virtual network in which I have been provided one of the LAN ipv4 address but it is acting as my WAN IP

It's commonly called "CGNAT" (carrier-grade NAT, i.e. NAT performed by your ISP) and fairly common with ISPs who have more customers than they have IP addresses.

so how do I deploy a website

You don't.
Longer answer – Call your ISP and ask them about ordering a dedicated IP address. Sometimes it's included in business plans, sometimes it's an additional monthly payment.
Alternative – some CDNs support having the web server connect out from a private network to the CDN relay (I think CloudFlare supports that).

I was trying to deploy a VPN server to access my work data on the go

Same as above. But if you can't get a dedicated IP address, it is possible to deploy a VPN on a cloud server, and then have both the  clients and your LAN connect out to that server, which will then act as a relay. (Can be set up with any kind of tunnel, e.g. OpenVPN or WireGuard or a mix.)
Some VPN software already have relays provided by the developer (for example, ZeroTier or Tailscale).

then how do people set their home labs?

@JagratSingh Either a) they don't host anything, since "home lab" doesn't actually imply hosting public servers anyway – it's a "lab", often it can remain completely private; or b) they have ISPs which do provide a dedicated IP address; or c) they host services through some kind of relay (a cheap VPS can act as both an ingress proxy for websites and as a hub for VPN access); or any combination thereof.
